# Spring boot Webflux(Reactive MongoDb) Unique Validation

Tags: spring-webflux

I tried to use the @Indexed(unique=true) annotation at my entity but it never throw an error for a duplicate value. The @postmapping is working good but no validation error.

Code Link: https://github.com/kuyabooo/reactiveMongoUniqueValidation.git
[User Entity Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxMn3.png)

Answer (score 1):

Do the fallowing Changes in Code

1. add fallowing property 
   spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation= true
2. you always need to specify the name of Index before creating so change syntax of **@Indexed**
   @Indexed(name = "pratik_dandre_index",unique = true)

***NOTE :*** you should use any name for **@Indexed**